# string split() in python 2.6

Tags: python, python-2.6

I'm facing a very simple situation while using string split() in python 2.6

issue is

I have a line in a file that reads

```
bacarat,baccarat
```

and then calling **split(",")** on it. which is resulting in

```
['bacarat', 'baccarat\r']
```

an extra **\r** is coming out of nowhere for all the lines.

this code is running on a server in some old python script which only support python2.6

any clue will be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: It does not come from nowhere : Your file has 2 lines (separated by \r).

Comment: @Golgauth, nowhere was just to highlight the fact that It was not obvious for me to expect \r there . anyway thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `str.strip` or `str.rstrip()` to remove that `\r`(carriage return) and then apply `str.split`:

```
>>> strs = 'bacarat,baccarat\r'
>>> strs.strip().split(',')
['bacarat', 'baccarat']
```

Using `str.rstrip`: removes only the trailing `'\r'`

```
>>> strs.rstrip('\r').split(',')
['bacarat', 'baccarat']
```

`str.strip` with no arguments removes all types of trailing and leading white spaces characters like `'\n'`, `'\r'`, `'\t'` etc.

Using `str.replace`: Note that this will replace all `'\r'` present at any location in the line.

```
>>> strs = 'bacarat,baccarat\r'
>>> strs.replace('\r','').split(',')
['bacarat', 'baccarat']
```

Comment: thanks, but why is that \r appearing in first place ? any clue ?

Comment: @Rohit Are you taking input from user on cmd?

Comment: I just checked the format of lines are "str" so basically ascii .  I opened the file in text-editor and enabled whitespace characters visible but didn't see any changes

Comment: @Rohit mac used to use `\r` for new lines

Comment: @Rohit use `repr()` to see the actual content of your lines, your file contains carriage returns.

Comment: @jamylak hmm so you are saying that the file was made in some old mac in which \r was used instead of \n and hence I am facing this bug?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary , thanks repr() worked . so I know that there is \r in every line

Comment: is there any way I can get rid of only that one \r at the end

Comment: @Rohit use `str.rstrip('\r')`, I already suggested that in my answer.
or replace `'\r'` with `''` using `str.replace('\r','')`

Comment: oh yup . sorry I forgot . one more doubt : so I wrote a new code in java based on same algorithm and java's split(',') is getting rid of \r as well. is this expected behaviour ?

Comment: @Rohit I've not used Java before , so can't say anything about that. Python's str.split() can get rid of such white space characters if you do something like this: `'bacarat baccarat\r'.split()`